# Specifying the server path in yii

Tags: php, css, yii

I m quite new to yii and I have written a crud and hosted in justhost.com. the problem is I have used a grid and I replaced the css of that grid with a customized css.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'my-model-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reinstallDatePicker',
'cssFile' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/gridViewStyle/gridview.css',
'columns' => array(
```

the problem is it doesnt Identify the css file path.
my file structure is like this
/mydirectory/css/gridViewStyle/gridview.css - css file location
/mydirectory/protected/views/memberdetails/filterMembers.

deployed in a linux server.

can some one help with this.

Comment: try `Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true)`

Comment: Take care with camel case filenames on Linux servers. File.css != file.css

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work if mydirectory is the root of your site. Do browser dev/network tools show the CSS file not being loaded? Maybe you mispelled a folder? Also check case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

May be Yii::app()->request->baseUrl not return you the basepath for the  site try to replace with "Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true)" or define a parameter in the config file for baseUrl.